# Concurrent reads from read only fields and writes in read/write fields in a shared object

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Lets say that I have this class:

```
public SharedObject {
  private int readOnlyField;
  private int readWriteField;

  public SharedObject(int field1, int field2) {
    this.readOnlyField = field1;
    this.readWriteField = field2;
  }

  public getField1() {...}

  public synchronized getField2() {...}

  public synchronized setField2(...) {...}
}
```

Can I have multiple threads that use these 3 methods concurrently?

Obviously I can with the last 2 synchronized methods, but I am not sure if getField1() can be executed concurrently with the other 2.

I think that the answer is yes, but just to be sure if I am missing some subtleties.

Comment: Certainly. Check out http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html#readLock() if that doesn't help I'll post a more thorough answer later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `getField1` it can be executed simultaneously by 2 threads without any wait and synchronization. And since you are not having any setter, and its value is initialized upon object instantiation, so there are no change of dirty read as well.

For `getField2` and `setField2`, no 2 threads and execute these methods at same time for the same instance of `SharedObject`.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Actually, getField2 and setField2 can not be executed by 2 threads simultaneously. That's the definition of the synchronized  keyword. No, but on a second read maybe I did not understand your last sentence. Can you elaborate on that? That scenario should not be possibile because 2 same instances must have the same lock. They are the same.

Comment: When there is no synchronization then Object's lock is not needed for execution, but then there is synchronization then thread will acquire the lock of that object/instance, which means that if any other thread wants to acquire same object lock then it has to wait. Now, it may so happen that 2 threads want the lock, if there are different priority then thread with higher priority will get the lock first, if same priority then first come first out or based on JVM. If object is not same, then this all doesn't come into picture because its all about lock of same object.

Comment: Yes, my statement became confusing. I edited. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Other thread(s) can execute a function which is not *marked as synchronized*.

So, in your case :

No two threads can execute `getField2` and `setField2` simultaneously. But `getField1()` can be executed simultaneously with either `getField2` or `setField2`